# How can I stop an Onchange event repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This code below runs the destinations area on this my homepage.  However it repeats the animation.  I need it to fade out whatever is currently displayed and replace with the selection from the dropdown.

I also need it to add a class to `.desarea` which is the value of the select box.

```
//Create destination switch
$('#regionselect').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('.regionDetail').fadeOut(function(){
         $('.'+selected.val()).slideDown();   
    });
    var count = $('.countrylist').length;
    $('.countrylist').slideUp(function(){
        if(!--count) {
           $('.'+selected.val()).slideDown();
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

`$('.'+selected.val()).slideDown();`

twice.  So it does it twice.

Comment: thats because it needs it for the left REGIONDETAILS and the right country list?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the two calls, but the fact that they are identical means it will run exactly the same thing twice.  All elements with a class of `selected.val()` will have `slideDown` called on them twice.

Comment: When a option is selected from the select box it should slide fade out the right hand list as well as the regiondetail then slide in whatever the matched value is...

Comment: But only fade in the new content once right?  So you shouldn't have it in BOTH callbacks.

Comment: Do you know how can i add the value to the class and also remove the the previous class value?

Comment: don't entirely understand what you mean, but try `removeClass` and `addClass`.